# list.removeall argument null exception not thrown

Tags: c#

I have list of type struct in which i temporarily add data and delete them when data is being written either to database or to a file, I am using `list.RemoveAll` method to remove item from the list.

The `list.RemoveAll` should throw `ArgumentNullException` if I call it on a list whose count is zero but it is not throwing any exception even if the count is zero.

```
    _dataNotWrittenToDb.RemoveAll(item => item.ScopeId == _a2Data.ScopeId);
    _dataWrittenToDB.RemoveAll(item => item.ScopeId == _a2Data.ScopeId);
```

Comment: *The list.RemoveAll should throw ArgumentNullException if I call it on a list whose count is zero* - where does it say that in the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx)?

Comment: It would have given you `ArgumentNullException` if you had written `_dataNotWrittenToDb.RemoveAll(null)`. Maybe that's what you misunderstood.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I got it now thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx)

**Exceptions**

```
Exception   Condition
ArgumentNullException   

match is null.
```

RemoveAll throw ArgumentNullException only when passed parameter is null, in your case it is not null

RemoveAll's job is to remove all elements that match to given condition, in your case no matching elements, no removes and no reason to return exception

Comment: The docs are confusing. But as it turns out if no matches are found it doesn't throw an exception. That part wasn't clear for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want exception, you can do something like this:

```
Predicate<YourItemStruct> p = item => item.ScopeId == _a2Data.ScopeId;

if (!_dataNotWrittenToDb.Exists(p))
  throw new Exception("No items exist to delete");
_dataNotWrittenToDb.RemoveAll(p); 
if (!_dataWrittenToDb.Exists(p))
  throw new Exception("No items exist to delete");
_dataWrittenToDb.RemoveAll(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

From List decompiled sources:

```
  public int RemoveAll(Predicate<T> match)
    {
      if (match == null)
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.match);
      int index1 = 0;
      while (index1 < this._size && !match(this._items[index1]))
        ++index1;
      if (index1 >= this._size)
        return 0;
      int index2 = index1 + 1;
      while (index2 < this._size)
      {
        while (index2 < this._size && match(this._items[index2]))
          ++index2;
        if (index2 < this._size)
          this._items[index1++] = this._items[index2++];
      }
      Array.Clear((Array) this._items, index1, this._size - index1);
      int num = this._size - index1;
      this._size = index1;
      ++this._version;
      return num;
    }
```

As you can see the only time when this method throws `ArgumentNullException` is when argument is actually equals `null`.

Answer (score -1):

If `count` is 0, that mean the list is empty. But the list exists. `Null` means the list does not exists.

`NullReferenceException` will be only thrown on `null` objects, not empties.

It's like an empty box in real life, compared to no box at all.

Comment: This has nothing to do with empty lists vs. the list reference being `null`. `ArgumentNullException` is (only) thrown when the *argument* is `null`, not when the list itself is `null` (in which case a `NullReferenceException` is thrown, but rather by the CLR than by the class itself).

Comment: Also, the OP doesn't even mention `NullReferenceException`, he's asking about `ArgumentNullException`.

Comment: yes, I was wrong. I though this was an extension method of IList. But this is a concrete method of list. If it was an extention method, the variable where the extension method is called is passed as an argument. This led me to the wrong guesS.

Comment: Ah, right, in that case the guess would have been right; I *think* the OP uses `List<T>`, though.